# Time complexity iterating over items in a SortedDict?

Tags: python, sorteddictionary, sortedcontainers

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

d = SortedDict(b=20, d=30, c=10, e=50, a=40)

# What is the time complexity of the following code?
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

I think the time complexity should be `nlog(n)` as getting an entry from a sorted dictionary costs `log(n)`, and even though we're iterating over this dictionary, we essentially perform the `get` operation n times. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding [the code](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers) correctly, you can iterate over the items of a SortedDict in O(n).

Internally, it uses a SortedList, which can iterate over all its elements in O(n) time. (SortedList is implemented as a list of lists, and it uses `itertools.chain_iterable()` to turn that into a single generator.) Once it identifies the correct item to access, it can look it up in a hash table, same as an ordinary dict. (The source code says "sorted dict inherits from dict to store items and maintains a sorted list of keys.")

How can this be possible, when any sorting algorithm based on comparisons must take least O(n log n)? When inserting into the SortedDict, that can take O(log n), since that's what the SortedList [takes for insertion.](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers/blob/9ff3270e5a5d1501918e5638e7ac32a40f922926/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.py#L1778) So inserting n items takes O(n log n), but iterating over them is only O(n).

Comment: It only uses SortedList internally for calls to `__iter__` _e.g._ something in the form `for k in d` ([here in the code](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers/blob/3f452674c3269ad0a792ce5ec0b33df7dc884bba/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.py#L256-L265)). `.items()` is not necessarily implemented in terms of SortedList.

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes, but - `items()` returns an object of type SortedItemsView. If you look at SortedItemsView, it is implemented as a subclass of collections.ItemsView. That class implements `__iter__` in terms of iterating over `self._mapping`. If you look at the superclass, collections.MappingView, `self._mapping` is set in the constructor. Referring back to `SortedDict.items()`, you can see that self._mapping is the SortedDict itself. In other words, `SortedDicct.items()` is defined in terms of `SortedDict.__iter__()`.

Answer (score 6):

[`SortedDict.items()`](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers/blob/3f452674c3269ad0a792ce5ec0b33df7dc884bba/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.py#L363-L371) calls `SortedItemsView(self)`, the constructor of which is [inherited](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers/blob/3f452674c3269ad0a792ce5ec0b33df7dc884bba/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.py#L708) from [`collections.abc.MappingView`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c86ee93d752d548550168cea68115398cc80d697/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L853) via [`collections.abc.ItemsView`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c86ee93d752d548550168cea68115398cc80d697/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L887), and `ItemsView` has the following special method:

```py
def __iter__(self):
    for key in self._mapping:
        yield (key, self._mapping[key])
```

So you're right that it is doing a lookup at each step. Here, `self._mapping` is a `SortedDict`. However, since [`SortedDict` is a subclass of `dict`](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers/blob/3f452674c3269ad0a792ce5ec0b33df7dc884bba/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.py#L43) that does not override `__getitem__`, it uses the standard `dict.__getitem__`, which is O(1) on average, better than O(log n).

Also note that the `for key in self._mapping:` above calls [`sortedDict.__iter__`](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers/blob/3f452674c3269ad0a792ce5ec0b33df7dc884bba/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.py#L256-L265), which calls [`SortedList.__iter__`](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers/blob/3f452674c3269ad0a792ce5ec0b33df7dc884bba/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.py#L920-L929), which calls `iterools.chain.from_iterable`, which runs in linear time.